# Data structure methods on clojure

Tags: list, clojure, tree

How can I transform this list:

```
'((A B) (A C) (C D) (B D) (D E) (D F))
```

Into something like

```
'(A (B (nil)) (C (D ((F (nil)) (E (nil))))))
```

Or whatever list best represent the tree:

```
          A
         / \       
        B   C
            |
            D
           / \
          E   F
```

Note that as C was the first to claim D as its child, the (B D) didn't add the D as the child of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all i would clean up the data, removing all the unnecessary pairs (in your case '(B D)), and build the adjacency map:

```
user> (def data '((A B) (A C) (C D) (B D) (D E) (D F)))
#'user/data

user> (def nodes-map (group-by first
                               (apply sorted-set-by 
                                      #(compare (second %1) (second %2))
                                      data)))
#'user/nodes-map

user> nodes-map
{A [(A B) (A C)], C [(C D)], D [(D E) (D F)]}
```

i removed the garbage using `sorted-set`, using the fact that it treats items to be equal using comparator, and keep only the first of them (in this case it considers `(C D) and`(B D) to be equal)

then i would construct the tree, using recursive function:

```
user> (defn to-tree [start nodes]
        (list start
              (if-let [connections (seq (nodes start))]
                (map #(to-tree (second %) nodes) connections)
                '(nil))))
#'user/to-tree

user> (to-tree 'A nodes-map)
(A ((B (nil)) (C ((D ((E (nil)) (F (nil))))))))
```

Comment: How would a tail call optimized version of to-tree look like?